# Is it possible to premultiply a Neural Network during the forward pass?

Tags: neural-networks, matrix, backpropagation

A Neural Network is essentially a set of weight matrices. Let's call them H1, H2, H3 etc (where each index is the hidden layer number).

In the forward pass, we take the input batch/dataset as a matrix X, which we then multiply with the first matrix H1 (after adding bias), and then H2 (after adding bias) and so on to get the output.

Could a speedup be achieved by multiplying the matrices out of order, before the result is multiplied with the input X? [Matrix Chain Optimization](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Matrix_chain_multiplication) could be used to reduce the raw number of computations. Also, the matrices could be multiplied in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were this possible, it would be a linear transformation and could be represented by a single matrix.  There are however nonlinear activation functions.  The very first activation function has to be applied to X transformed by the first parameters.  Information therefore does literally flow through each step of the network, it's not a single transformation.